# null terminator gives trouble with string length when comparing

Tags: c++, string, comparison

I'm trying to compare 2 strings by "==" operator.
when i print the string both are identical.

but length of one is bigger by one, i figured it is the null terminator.

any way to ignore this when comparing??

Thanks!!

```
City* Adjutancy::FromStringToCity(string cityName) const
{
 for (list<City*>::const_iterator it=m_citiesList.begin();it!=m_citiesList.end();it++)
  if ((*it)->GetCityName()==cityName) //this fails
   return *it;
 return NULL;
}
```

and

```
string GetCityName() const {return m_cityName;}
```

creation

```
private: 
 string m_cityName;
```

and

```
FromStringToCity(toAdd->GetCityOfBase());
```

and

```
string Base::GetCityOfBase() const
{
 return m_baseCity;
}
```

and

```
private:
  string m_baseCity;
```

This is all, BTW this works on Visual Studio in windows, but now when I transfer it to Linux Kate - this where it fails.

Comment: Are you using `std::string` or string literals or C strings, or...?

Comment: @Nadav:  Then you need to post some code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The NULL terminator is not included in the length of an std::string, and the fact that an std::string even has a NULL terminator is an implementation detail and not a requirement.  There might be an invisible (non-printable) character in the string, or a multi-byte character which looks similar to a regular ASCII character, which is causing the lengths to be different, even though the strings look the same.  Can you post the code so we can see what's going on here?

Comment: You are still missing the important part - how are you creating the strings?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should pass strings by reference to avoid unnecessary copying.  Your function should be `FromStringToCity(const string& cityName) const`

Comment: @Charles:  However, if you append a null terminator yourself to a `std::string`, that will increase the size.  It's not necessarily the case that `strlen(s.c_str()) == s.size()`.

Comment: @Charles: `std::string` objects can contain `'\0'` characters. It's unusual for an application to want to do this and it's probably a bug in most cases if one ends up in the string, but the interface for `std::string` permits it (though the `c_str()` becomes quite a bit less useful).

Comment: Nadav, you still don't show us how you are creating the `string` objects in the first place. You probably somewhere create a `string` from a `char` array or some other input?

Comment: @Georg I'm getting a txt file , i read its data into a a list of strings by getline(infile,line); then put it in the string by substr.. i can post the whole process but i'm sure not transfering it from char to string

Comment: How about showing us that part and sample input lines that reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If these are string literals in quotes or character arrays, they won't compare because you're comparing the pointer addresses, not the strings themselves. If they're `std::string`s, it should work just fine.

If they're both std::string and one is longer than the other, we'd need to see how you're assigning the values to detect the problem.

**Edit:** After reading numerous comments, I believe your extra character is not a null terminator but a line-feed. You'll need to strip it off as you read the file.

Comment: when i debugged it i got the same data only one had /0 at the last index

Comment: the question made it clear the types involved were strings.  Your edit says you've read numerous comments and concluded it might be a linefeed.  Actually - as per my answer - it's probably a carriage return, and they're not the same thing.

Comment: @Tony, you might be right - which is why I already gave your answer an upvote. Certainly it's some character which is usually invisible. It seems a quirk of fate robbed you of the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765454/null-terminator-gives-trouble-with-string-length-when-comparing/3765831#3765831

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess you're reading a file with carriage return characters.  In Windows, a carriage-return / linefeed combination (ASCII 13 / 10 decimal) delimits text lines.  On Linux/UNIX, only a linefeed is needed.  When you read in the strings on Linux, it will retain the carriage return character in the string, rather than stripping it as it does on Windows.  You need to check if the last character is a carriage return and - if so - remove it:

```
if (str.size() and str[str.size() - 1] == '\r')
    str.erase(str.size() - 1);
```

BTW / when you print (to a terminal device) a string with a carriage return, it will simply move the cursor back to the left-hand column after displaying the string.  It's easier to spot if you put a quote before and after, e.g.

```
std::cout << "my_string \"" << my_string << "\"\n";
```

Then if my_string held "text\r", you'd see...

```
"y_string "text
```

...weird enough to ring an alarm bell.

Answer (score 2):

Now that the immediate problem you knew about has (apparently) been dealt with, let me advise that you throw away that code and replace it with something else entirely.

In particular, you seem to be using `std::list` to implement what's really intended to be a map -- i.e., lets you look up a city by name. The standard library already has a map (named `std::map`) that's more efficient and easier to use. A linked list may not be the worst possible data structure for the job at hand, but at least based on what you've shown that you're doing with it, it's certainly *one* of the worst choices available.

From the looks of things, you could use:

```
std::map<std::string, City> cityList;
```

or *maybe*:

```
std::map<std::string, City *> cityList;
```

and be a lot better off. Searches would be logarithmic instead of linear (i.e., normally quite a bit faster, especially with a large number of cities), and management would be cleaner and simpler in general (e.g., adding information about a city would be something like:

```
City chicago;
// fill in data about Chicago

cityList["Chicago"] = chicago;
```

Answer (score 1):

do

```
strcmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) == 0
```

this will compare them as null terminated c strings

really you should strip off the trailing NULL when you create the strings tho.

Comment: @visionary - what the heck does that mean. I am not using == for string compare I am using strcmp. And what does reference semantics mean for C code

Comment: @nadav - then you dont have the problem you think you have. Use a debugger

Comment: do you really want to recommend use of strcmp (CRT) for std::string? operator== should work fine once string setup is sorted out.

Comment: @steve - he asked how to do the compare in the case where the string has trailing \0, I told him. I also told him to fix the string (so that == would work)