# null terminator problem while comparing identical char*

Tags: c++, string

i try to compare between 2 char* identical strings,but one of them contains a null terminator at the end.
i've been looking through the internet and understood that it's not recommendable to remove the null terminator char cause it will make the string unstable.
what other methods can i use?

the comparing function:

```
int StringCompare(const char* str1, const char* str2)  
{
    int size1 = strlen(str1), size2 = strlen(str2), min = 0, index =0;  
    bool bigger1 = true;  
    if(size1>size2)  
        min=size2;  
    else  
        min=size1;  
    for(index=0;index<min;index++)  
    {  
        if(str1[index]>str2[index])  
            return 1;  
        if(str1[index]<str2[index])  
            return (-1);  
    }  
    if(size1==size2)  
        return 0;  
    if(min==size1)  
        return (-1);  
    else  
        return 1;  
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Why are you rolling your own StringCompare, there's strcmp found in the strings.h?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: strcmp checks the lengths first and if they're different returns that they're not identical.

Comment: even if the content is identical , the size is different because of the null terminator and i get that  they are not identical

Comment: Are you really trying to ensure both strings start with the same characters?

Comment: @shiran bar:  Wrong.  You're finding lengths with `strlen()`, and `strlen()` looks for the zero-byte terminator.  Therefore, to work, both strings have to have one, and anything after that is not part of the string.  As this question stands, it's not really answerable.  Could you specify what you're trying to do, what you expect with the above code, and what you're getting?

Comment: @shiran:  Also, you're wrong about `strcmp()`.  It compares characters until it hits the end of a string (the zero-byte or null terminator), and if all characters have been identical it then checks lengths.  Checking the length first would mean two passes over the strings, which is a lot less efficient than I'd expect to see in a C standard library function.

Comment: i'm trying to compare the two strings contents until one reaches its null terminator, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @shiran bar:  Yes, and you have done that (barring possible typos and reversed conditions my quick scan may have missed).  What is your question?

Comment: How can two strings be identical if they are not the same length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `strlen` which **requires** a null terminator at the end of the string. If one of the strings you pass doesn't have a terminator, you are guaranteed to fail.

Comment: what other function can tell me the size of char*?

Comment: @shiran bar, There's the `sizeof` operator, but that's probably not what you want.  What are you trying to accomplish?  If you can clarify your goals, we can better help you understand what you need to do.

Comment: @shiran bar, the classic `char *` string inherited from C ends with a null by definition. You can use `std::string` instead which contains the length as a separate attribute, or you can pass a length into the function along with the strings.

Comment: i want to compare the actual content of the strings, without considering the null terminator at the end of one of them. is there a function that can do that or returns the size of a string without counting the null terminator?

Comment: strlen doesn't count the NUL at the end, and strn?cmp doesn't consider the NUL.

Comment: we tried working with string instead but the same problem occurs, the size is still different.

Comment: @Matt Kane, `strncmp` does consider the NUL.

Comment: @shiran bar, the problem may not be what you think it is. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3765454/5987

Comment: we tried using strncmp it doesn't work as well, or maybe we're doing it wrong:                                                                  int StringCompare(const char* str1, const char* str2)
    {
     int size1 = strlen(str1), size2 = strlen(str2), max = 0, index =0;
    
     if(size1<size2)
      max=size2;
     else
      max=size1;
     return (strncmp(str1,str2,max));
    }

Comment: If you want to compare two arrays of characters (perhaps char*'s) without regard to contained nuls, you want `memcmp`, which requires the length of the arrays as a third parameter.  I hope you know how long they are.

Answer (score 5):

Use std::string, that's what it's for. Failing common sense, use strcmp().

Answer (score 4):

You're calling strlen on both, so they better both have NULs (not NULL) at the end. Once you get to one of the NUL, you need to stop comparing, because the string is done! That's it! Any subsequent data does not belong to that string.

Answer (score 4):

Please read this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124935/c-strings-confusion/2125429#2125429) about C Strings and understand it. ALL c strings requires a nul terminator to signify to the C runtime, that the end of string has been reached. The nul terminator is `\0`. Notice the distinction between the usage of nul and null, in order to clear any potential confusions - when dealing with strings, its nul, with pointers its NULL!

Comment: Because you are simply referring to another post (even if it is your own), I would recommend you make this a CW answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would hope that **both** your `char*` strings have null terminators at the end! The null terminator is what enables functions like `strlen` to determine the length, and know when the string ends.

Answer (score 3):

If you know which of the two strings has null terminator, you can call strlen() on it and use that as the length of both strings. But that's a terrible hack - you're not really comparing anything.

Suppose you have two strings:

```
"abc\0"
"abcdef\0"
```

Is string 2 null-terminated? Or is "def\0" part of it just random garbage?

The only way to be sure is to null-terminate all strings.

Answer (score 3):

If only one of the strings is null terminated, you should modify your **for** loop to end when the null is reached for either string, and omit the strlen() call.

```
for(index=0;;index++)  
{  
    if(!str1[index]) {
        if(!str2[index]) 
            return 0; // strings are equal in length
        return -1; // str1 < str2 since str2 is longer
    }
    if(!str2[index]) 
        return 1;  // str1 > str2 since str1 is longer     

    if(str1[index]>str2[index])  
        return 1;  
    if(str1[index]<str2[index])  
        return (-1);  
}
```

Note that this has the same effect as Matteo Italia's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can't possibly work unless *both* `str1` and `str2` have null terminators.  Otherwise, how do you (or `strlen`) know how long they are?

If the real question is **"How can I work with strings that contain embedded NUL characters?"**, you should use a `vector<char>` or similar.  You're no longer talking about strings, because by definition strings are NUL-terminated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to compare 2 strings and you cannot be sure they will both be null terminated, you're method signature needs to take the size of the passed strings as arguments, otherwise strlen will tell you how many bytes there are from the char* pointer to the first memory location of 0.